# Solve Riccati Equations by hand

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, control-systems

I'm in the midst writing a bit about LQR problems and would like to show that some things in mathematica can be tested by trying to write such problems out by ones self, However I cannot seem to find a solution to the Riccati matrix equation myself, or atleast, I get a null answer from `Solve[]`

take an ssm of a pendulum:

```
pen = StateSpaceModel[{\[Phi]''[t] + g/l Sin[\[Phi][t]] == u[t]}, {{\[Phi]'[t], 0}, { \[Phi][t], \[Pi]}}, {{u[t], 0}}, {\[Phi][t]}, t, SystemsModelLabels -> {{"u"}, {"\[Phi]"}, {"\[Phi]", "\[Phi]'"}}]
```

Try internal functions:

```
solpen = LQRegulatorGains[pen, {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1}}}]
```

Try somewhat by hand:

```
Module[{a, b, q, r, p},
 {a, b} = { Normal[pen][[1]], Normal[pen][[2]]};
 {q, r, p} = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1}}, {{0}, {0}}};
 Inverse[
   r] . (Transpose[b] . RiccatiSolve[{a, b}, {q, r, p}] + 
    Transpose[p])]
```

Try even deeper by hand:

```
Module[{q, r, p, a, b, x, x1, x2},
 {a, b} = { Normal[pen][[1]], Normal[pen][[2]]} /. {g -> 9.81, l -> 1};
 {q, r, p} = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1}}, {{0}, {0}}};
 x = {{x1, 0}, {0, x2}};
 Solve[Transpose[a] . x + 
    x . a - (x . b + p) . 
     Inverse[r] . (Transpose[b] . x + Transpose[p]) + q == 0, {x1, x2}]
 ]
```

This provides a simple empty list as an answer...and I can't see to get past this.

How would one solve the continous riccati equation within mathematica by hand? Or Can atleast show me where I'm going wrong.

**Update**

After digging in the doc, I found an example where a solution is calculated via the hamilton matrix, however this solution does not give the same stabilizing gains calculated from the previous examples,

```
Module[{q, r, p, a, b, x, x1, x2, vals, vecs, stableBasis, 
  selfRiccati},
 {a, b} = { Normal[pen][[1]], Normal[pen][[2]]} /. {g -> 9.81, l -> 1};
 {q, r, p} = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1}}, {{0}, {0}}};
 {vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[ArrayFlatten[( {
      {a, -b . Inverse[r] . Transpose[b]},
      {-q, -Transpose[a]}
     } )]];
 stableBasis = Extract[vecs, Position[vals, _?(# < 0 &), {1}]];
 {{x1, x2}} = Partition[stableBasis, {2, 2}];
 selfRiccati = x2 . Inverse[x1] // Simplify;
 Inverse[r] . (Transpose[b] . selfRiccati + Transpose[p])
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an empty list because the problem you are posing does not have a solution. Following your steps but letting `x` be a full matrix instead of diagonal you will see that

```
{a, b} = {Normal[pen][[1]], Normal[pen][[2]]}
{q, r, p} = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1}}, {{0}, {0}}}
x = {{x11, x12}, {x12, x22}}
```

is such that

```
ricc = Transpose[a].x+x.a - (x.b+p).Inverse[r].(Transpose[b].x+Transpose[p]) + q
```

evaluates to

> {{1 - x11^2 + 2 x12, -x11 x12 + x22 + g x11 l^-1},
> {-x11 x12 + x22 + g x11 l^-1, 1 - x12^2 + 2 g x12 l^-1}}

The last entry, `1 - x12^2 + 2 g x12 l^-1` can only be zero if `x12` is nonzero. You can solve for the full matrix solution using

```
Thread[Flatten[ricc] == 0]
Solve[%, Union[Flatten[x]]]
```

in which case you obtain the complete set of four solutions to this equation. Only one of them will be the stabilizing solution you are looking for.

Comment: could you explain why the solution contains "x11$13278365" and other "$junk" when using module, or rather, know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Variables that you declare in module will be defined locally with funny names. If you want a solution in terms of global symbols (that will look clean) you have to pass them as parameters of your module, which is the way I recommend, or simply do not define them in your module, in which case it will assume they are in the global context.

Comment: I'm about to mark your answer as correct, (which it clearly is) however, something nags at me, in that I give `RiccatiSolve[]` the exact same matricies that you say give no solution when done by hand, requiring a different form of matrix, which gives 12 solutions, of which only 2 are correct...and not those along the main diagonal of the matrix x as I'd expect...are you aware of why or how riccati solve ends up coming up with the correct stablizing solution?

Comment: The Riccati solver calculates the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the Hamiltonean matrix associated with the Riccati equation. This matrix is symplectic and the eigenvalues have symmetry relative to both the real and imaginary axis. The solver proceeds by sorting and select the half set of eigenvalues which correspond to the stable closed-loop poles. In your case you can look at the eigenvalues of the resulting matrix $x$ and chose the one that is positive definite.